# How to protect top row in all sheets in work

Tags: excel, vba

I cant figure out how to write a vba macro to protect the first row in any active sheet in a workbook

All help appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by **protecting** the top row? To protect all sheets but only the first row to be locked for modifications? Or what? Then, what do you mean by "any active sheet"? Only a sheet can be active at a specific moment. Do you want protecting the sheet contents of the first row **only when it is active**? An Unprotect the other ones? Or what?

Comment: You woud do this: Mark all rows as unlocked. Mark firs row as locked. Then protect the sheet. Use macro recorder to see how this is done by VBA. Write a loop around that to do that for all sheets. If you get stuck or errors come back with your code and your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not answer my clarification questions...

The next event code will assume the next scenario: It locks the first row of the active sheet and protect it (during the `Activate` event code) and also `UnProtect` the previously activated sheet, memorizing its name.

1. Plaese, copy the next declaration line **on top of `ThisWorkbook` code module** (in the declarations area):

```
  Public lastActSheet As String
```

It may also be `Private` if you will not need to use it from a standard module

2. Copy the next event code also in `ThisWorkbook` code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal sh As Object)
    Const protPass As String = "1234" 'use here the protect/unprotect password
    If lastSheetName <> "" Then
        Debug.Print "You are coming from " & ThisWorkbook.lastSheetName 'just to prove the existence of another previously activated sheet
        Worksheets(lastActSheet).Unprotect protPass 'unprotect the previously protected sheet
    End If
    'protect the first row of the active sheet:
    If sh.ProtectContents Then sh.Unprotect protPass 'just in case, if the sheet remained protected (before closing and saving wb)...
    sh.cells.Locked = False  'unlock all the active sheet cells
    sh.rows(1).Locked = True 'lock the first row
    sh.Protect protPass      'protect the active sheet

    lastActSheet = sh.name 'memorize the sheet name for the next (another) sheet activation processing.
End Sub
```

You can skip the part of unprotecting the previously activated sheet if you will not need (in the future) that all the other sheets, except the active one, to **NOT be protected**.

If you need to do that in on step, protecting all sheets please, use the next code:

```
Sub ProtectFirstRowInAllSheets()
   Const protPass As String = "1234"
   Dim sh As Worksheet
     For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.ProtectContents Then sh.Unprotect protPass 'if an error, check what passord has been used and unprotect that sheet...
        sh.cells.Locked = False
        sh.rows(1).Locked = True
        sh.Protect protPass
     Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your work here - and my sincerest apologies. I didn't put enough effort into explaining my full scenario. I'll close this post.

Comment: @Campbell If all my suppositions based on what I placed the above answer are wrong, you can do whatever you want. But if one of the two cases solved your problem, it would be good to let the question as it is, confirming what part of the answer code fit your need. Our main goal here is to make as many people as possible learning. And somebody searching for one of the two solutions can learn from the code...